# Java swing drag and drop notepad

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, editor, draw

I want to implement an editor where I need to have different shapes on the left-side panel and drag and drop different shapes on the right-side panel where i should be able to drag and adjust the shapes in the editor and save the drawingpad in a file in swing.

Can anyone help with that? how do I get a a dragable shapes and simultaneously add or remove after selecting a particular shape from my drawing pad.

Comment: Help with what? [What have you already done](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?  You haven't told us anything about what you've already written, or how your drawing pad works, so how are we supposed to answer questions about how to do things with it?

Comment: I have implemented a notepad with file menu options and added the shapes on the left-side panel, i need to drop and drag the shapes on the right-side panel, this part i need some help.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a Shape container package ([like my Area one](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape))

Second, if you want to drag and drop shapes from a toolbar panel, you'll need a MouseInputListener to listen for toolbar clicks on the shapes, change the cursor, and handle the drop on mouseReleased

Good luck!